# Query a Django Many-to-Many through relationship without iteration?

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm, saleor

I am looking to organise products within categories in a way that is specific to the selected category. A product can be part of multiple categories and so I'm using a Many-To-Many Through relationship to define them.

I have the following 4 models:

```
class Category(MPTTModel, ModelWithMetadata, SeoModel, PublishableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    ...
​
​
class Product(SeoModel, ModelWithMetadata, PublishableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    category_management = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category,
        related_name="category_managed_products",
        through="OrderedCategoryManagedProduct",
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Category Management",
    )
    ...
​
​
class OrderedCategoryManagedProduct(SortableModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cmp_products"
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cmp_categories"
    )
    added_automatically = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["sort_order"]
​
    def get_ordering_queryset(self):
        return OrderedCategoryManagedProduct.objects.all()
​
​
class SortableModel(models.Model):
    sort_order = models.IntegerField(editable=False, db_index=True, null=True)
​
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
​
    def get_ordering_queryset(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Unknown ordering queryset")
​
    ...
```

The SortableModel is from the [Saleor Legacy Views application](https://github.com/mirumee/legacy-views/blob/master/saleor/core/models.py#L10)

Is it possible to query a particular category and receive a queryset of the products within it in - ordered by `sort_order` - without having to iterate through all the products individually?

Comment: So you want to receive a sorted queryset of a particular `Category`? If yes, can you please also note how you want the query to be sorted?

Comment: I want to receive a sorted queryset of products within a particular `Category`. The products need to be ordered by the `sort_order` inherited by the `OrderedCategoryManagedProducts`